# How do I find out where my application depends on BouncyCastle and log4net?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dependencies, .net-assembly

My application has a references to two packages **BouncyCastle** and **log4net**:

[image: Installed Nuget packages]

How do I find if my application depends on them? I can't work out if I need to deploy them with my installer. I have noted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304859/should-i-distribute-log4net-with-my-releases).

**Update**

I am not sure when this file App.Config is used by my application, but it does have a reference to log4net:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.22.0" newVersion="4.2.22.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.15.0" newVersion="1.2.15.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Anyone know what this file is used for? Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431742/what-is-app-config-for) article explaining what it is for. But it looks to me that maybe this **log4net** is installed from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/). But it is not clear if I have to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the reference and try compiling and running? If there are compile time errors you can catch where the dependencies are.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that approach is all else fails. But if anyone doe shave any knowledge about these two and how they may be used in general I am interested. I added some notes about the log4net.